# How to determine the height of a pole using a mirror and a subject's height?

Tags: trigonometry

You, $5$ feet tall, come upon $2$ friends arguing about the height of a telephone pole
$20$ feet away. You want to help them determine the height but only have a $10$ ft
tape measure, and a mirror. How would you determine the height of the pole and what is the height?

I am so lost with where to even begin with this question.

Comment: Step 1: Walk the $20$ feet to the pole. 

Step 2: Chop it down with a handy ax ([or a convenient herring](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DopGxUAoAY)).

Step 3: Apply tape measure to find the height (length now).

Step 4: Smash the mirror for funsies.

Answer (score 2):

Using the tape measure you can find distances even greater than 10 feet along the ground by measuring from starting point to an ending point, then standing at the ending point beginning again.

[image: telephonepole]

(this answer assumes the ground is flat)

Begin by standing sufficiently far enough away from the telephone pole in such a way that you have a straightline path to the pole.

With the tapemeasure fully extended, place the mirror on the ground at the end of the tape measure exactly 10 feet away from you in the direction of the telephone pole.  (you might want to ask one of your argumentative friends to hold the mirror and/or tapemeasure if they feel like ending the argument).  Looking down at the mirror at the spot precisely 10 feet away from you, if you see the very top of the telephone pole then you are standing in the correct position.  If not, then either move closer or further away from the telephone pole, moving the tapemeasure and mirror as well.

Once you have located the spot where when looking at the mirror you see the very top of the telephone pole, measure the distance from the mirror to the telephone pole.  The height of the pole will be one half the distance measured.

---

With the current wording of the problem, the actual height of the pole is unknown and there is not enough tools or information to solve explicitly.  You can creatively use angles of the mirror to ascertain the height from where you are standing 20 feet away, but it will be difficult to measure exactly.

---

An alternate solution which allows you to stand in one place (but requires the mirror to move, have your friends do that), since you are 20 feet away and the telephone pole is presumably taller than you (else, why are they arguing), using the same idea as before to utilize similar triangles, find the spot between you and the telephone pole such that when you look down at the mirror on the measuring tape you see the top of the telephone pole.

[image: telephonepole2]

The height of the telephone pole will be $\frac{100-5x}{5}$, where $x$ is the distance from you to the mirror (along the ground).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information, it's been a tremendous help

Comment: @Anne I'm glad to hear that you found my answer useful.  You are welcome to keep this question open for some time more to encourage additional answers (which might be different than my own), but after enough time I would encourage you to [accept an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so as to let other people know that the question has been resolved, removing it from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: This is a very well-written answer. (+1)